# How many episodes will Dragon Ball Super have?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Is there any official source stating how many episodes Dragon Ball Super will have? With all the open stories it has (Bills, Champa, the multi universe tournament, Zeno-sama, Zamasu, Black Goku, etc) I can't image them all fitting in the once rumored 100 episodes.

Comment: I  could not find any source that could answer your question. But I actually think there will be much more than 100 episodes. 1st, I think they'll want to keep going as long as it's popular and there remains story to be told. 2nd, the Future Trunks arc has only recently begun and I would expect another 20 or so episodes to finish it and we know it'll be followed by an inter-universe tournament. Lastly, we finally know the finite size of the Dragon Ball world, and who sits at the top of it (Zeno-sama). I think the series will take time to explore its world in depth before drawing a conclusion.

Comment: I have been doing some research and read a variety of different things. It definitely has been renewed through 72 episodes, and many rumors speculate that it will get at least 100 or more. I found a couple [sites](http://en.yibada.com/articles/112541/20160329/how-many-dragon-ball-super-episodes-are-there-before-dbs-ends.htm) that stated it would be at least 145 episodes in length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until now, it is officially confirmed to have ***at least*** [72 episodes](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/2016/05/23/dragon-ball-super-dvd-blu-ray-boxes-4-6-announced/) of DBS. [Rumors](http://attackofthefanboy.com/news/rumor-dragon-ball-super-go-long-100-episodes/) have shown that it will be 100 episodes, or even more if it's getting more popularity, but all of that is ***not true***. Rumors are rumors, it is not yet confirmed, all we can do is to wait for upcoming news.